# Receiving error message 'Extension host terminated unexpectedly.' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been looking around and I haven't found any answers to my issue.
I keep getting this error "**Extension host terminated unexpectedly.**"    and I have tried removing all of my extensions, reinstalling the program, trying different versions of vscode including the insider versions.

The way I get this isssue isn't from trying to use the debugger or trying to use some sort of extension, as I said before I removed all of them and the error keeps on coming back, it's simply from opening the application. I'm not entirely sure how to continue? I have had to use another editor because the error just doesn't go away. I will just have to wait for another update of Visual Studio Code I assume? I've had the issue since tuesday this week, guessing since the latest update.

[image: Error message.]

Above is the error message I get. It is closed by `esc` but reappears very shortly after, every time.

[image]

When I open developer tools, this is what I find in the console.
Running vscode from command prompt with `Code.exe --disable-extensions` doesn't help.
Visual Studio Code version:   1.16.1

I appreciate any help.

[Linking my github issue on Microsoft/vscode as reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35271)

Comment: Any light-weight solution to a complicated problem will eventually evolve into a state where nobody can see the light anymore.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but your fix didn't work. 
 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65304

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Linking my github issue on Microsoft/vscode as reference.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35271)
It ended up being one of the base extensions that runs on startup that was the root of the problem.

In my case the `git` in extensions folder was causing it.
`"git.enabled": false` was not doing the trick so I had to remove the git folder altogether for the error to disappear.

Answer (score 44):

I had the same error after updating vsc to **v. 1.31.0**.

Disabling **Live Server** Extension worked for me.

Here's the error i'm getting having the extension enabled.

[image: Error Image after enabling Live Server]

Comment: Disabling Live Server worked for me as well removing live sass compiler. I think you should remove anything that has to do with starting a server plugin

Comment: Using Live Server alone (with sass compiler disabled) seems to be working for me

Comment: Thanks, I was having problems with Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers extension

Comment: Disabling live server worked for me too but it also disabled live sass since it depends on it

Answer (score 12):

I started getting this error when vscode automatically updated to March 2020 (version 1.44). I have tried various suggestions given in the forum and over the internet but none of them worked.

**What worked for me:** I downloaded January 2020 (version 1.42) build from https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42 and ran over the previous installation without uninstalling and surprisingly, the error disappeared and all extensions are loading and working properly.

**I tried following things and non of them worked:**

1. I disabled all the installed extension from GUI.
2. uninstalled all the extension and installed again.
3. removed the left-over extensions from Windows %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions.
4. tried launching from the command prompt with --disable-extensions option.

Comment: Thank you, Pankaj! I have spent my whole day but I only able to resolve the issue by going down to the previous version. Worked like charm!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used typescript-hero extension. Disabling this extension fixed my problem.
It's temporal fix but maybe will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled all the extensions with name **Live** for example **Live Server, Live Share etc** and restarted my vscode again and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was happening due to HTML CSS Support extension. so i removed it and restarted vs code and voila! it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall few extensions related to Java (debugger for java, Test runner for java, extension pack for java etc) to make the error go away.

Click on the developer tool option that popups and see if it has the extension which is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue and it was because of **Color Highlight** Extension. I just uninstalled **Color Highlight** Extension and its working fine and ***NO ERROR***.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Me too. My failure has no "Code":

> Extension host terminated unexpectedly. Code:  null  Signal:  SIGABRT

MessageService.ts[image]

Comment: Did you try to reinstall git, if you have it installed?

Comment: I haven't. What makes you think this is related to git?

Comment: Well, all I know is that the issue no longer happened to me after I had reinstalled git. The file `vscode.git` in the base extension folder was causing  the error for me, so I had to remove it. I stopped getting the error but when I tried to use the debugger again the extension host died. So I am using my laptop when I want to use the debugger - which is a bit silly, but oh well!

Comment: Good point. I guess i didn't think this was git related because it only happens for one of my projects.
I'll try it!

Comment: I think I got lucky - just reinstalled vscode and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same error message after accepting a permission to run a program on the extension **livepreview**. It corrupted all other extensions where it could not find the commands. I deleted all extension files and reinstalled the other extensions without a problem. I tried **liveserver** again but It never prompted me again for permissions and still, the error message keeps occurring.  I'm assuming **liveserver** was trying to ask the computer permission to run a local server after which is still accepted but something else is interfering with the computer being able to translate from the program to actually building and accessing the local server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the live server extension was causing this issue in 1.31.0v of VS Code. After uninstalling the extension it started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was from the extension "Todo Tree". It was breaking on a particularly large file in my project (13.7mb), with the error saying the file was over the max-size for a node-buffer (used by the C regex matcher).

Resolved the issue by disabling the extension.

I also opened an issue for it here: https://github.com/Gruntfuggly/todo-tree/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with following error in my VSCode console.

```
`1: node::DecodeWrite
 2: node::InternalCallbackScope::Close
 3: v8::internal::VirtualMemory::TakeControl
 4: v8::internal::PerThreadAssertScope<4,1>::PerThreadAssertScope<4,1>
 5: v8::internal::operator<<
 6: v8::internal::operator<<
 7: 00000073ECF04481`
```

I solved it by uninstalling Angular Console extension. Not sure if it was that particular extension or some other memory issue but problem went away as soon as I uninstalled that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all Extensions which are located in a per user extensions folder. Depending on your platform, the location is in the following folder:

- Windows `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- macOS
  `~/.vscode/extensions`
- Linux `~/.vscode/extensions`

Restart vscode and start installing extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this caused , but the Antivirus was throwing popups that something like extensionprocess.js file was repaired.

Disabled the Antivirus and re-installed Vscode and it was back to normal.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me:
Ctrl+Shift+P --> type: "*Disable*"

[image]

and click *Disable all installed extensions*
(alternatively click *Disable all installed extensions for this Workspace*)

Then go to extensions panel on the left and re-enable slowly those that you really need.

See which extension (or their combination) triggers that error.

- It will be highly appreciated which extenstion/combination you'll find guilty as there may be several of them, and different in time...

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Visual Studio Code introduced an in-built [extension bisect utility](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) that catches the erroneous extension causing the extension host to crash:

[image: Extension Bisect Utility]

It uses the binary search method and divides the number of extensions into two equal parts until it finds the extension causing the trouble.

For this, it requires the user to keep an eye on if they face the crash when the window restarts a couple of times:

[image: Working 1]

If the crash is not encountered, press on **I can't reproduce** until you face one.

At the end, the culprit is found:

[image: The culprit extension]

This feature saves hell a lot of time!

Answer (score -1):

for me, it was code runner extension I just disabled it.