# Extension host unexpectedly teminated (vscode)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

i cannot debug or run my code on vscode for java however i have installed all the extensions needed for java package. while i open the vscode editor it gives  a message "extension host unexpectedly terminated"

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457994/receiving-error-message-extension-host-terminated-unexpectedly-in-visual-stud ?

Comment: Probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160837/extension-host-terminated-unexpectedly-in-vs-code/61161079#61161079

Answer (score 1):

Go to the antivirus software that you used in your pc, then add the extensionhostprocess.js in the ignored processes while scanning. I encountered the same issue, and my antivirus popped up saying extensionhostprocess.js has been repaired. So I restored it from the quarantine process, then everything worked fine for me.