# Why is VSCode "Unable to open Extension. An unknown error occurred."?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is my first time installing and using VSCode, and when I tried installing [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension, it let me peek quickly at the extension page before closing it and displaying this notification (Screenshot attached):

> Unable to open 'Extension: Prettier - Code formatter': An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details..

[VSCode screenshot: Notification at bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxPxk.jpg)

It's doing this with all other extensions. Searched for a solution but found nothing applicable.
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You might use VSCode's developer console to learn more about the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765782/the-use-of-developer-tools-in-vs-code However, I do suggest you open an issue with its vendor, https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues who should have better knowledge on what might be wrong.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61172590/extension-host-unexpectedly-teminated-vscode possibly related.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It happens that, this is a problem with the Egyptian ISPs' default DNS servers, which are most probably blocking some of Microsoft servers.

The solution (in case you live in Egypt):

1. clear DNS cache using `ipconfig /flushdns` command on Windows cmd (For [Other OS](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/internet-and-networking/clearing-the-dns-cache-on-your-computer)).
2. change the default DNS servers in your router settings to Google's 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 (or Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 or any other DNS server you trust).
3. restart VSCode and try installing extensions.

Hopefully, everything will work fine by now.

Check this [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95427) for more insight.

Comment: This is how to configure Windows 10 to set DNS: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

Comment: In my case, you don't need to proceed to step 2 onward. I flushed the DNS and it worked (Windows 10)

Comment: If you cannot/don't want to edit DNS settings, you can open code with the `--ignore-certificate-errors`, install the extensions you need, then restart without the flag.

Answer (score 8):

It probably is because of the **certificate check**.

Below solution works for me in CentOS 7 (Linux).

**Step 1.** Change the file `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop`

Open the file `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop`,
then modify the Exec value with adding `--ignore-certificate-errors` before `%F`:

```
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch --ignore-certificate-errors %F
```

Save the file with typing `sudo` in the begining.

[image: the file code.desktop]

**Step 2.** Close all windows of vs code instances.

**Step 3.** Back to the terminal, use below command to open VS code:

```sh
code --ignore-certificate-errors
```

**Step 4.** Click extension button in the left side bar.

Click any extension like "Ruby" by Peng Lv, if the images in the `Details` page can be seen successfully, perhaps the issue is solved.

**Step 5.** Try to continue to install the extensions you need.

Just enjoy! May it be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I use VSCode behind the company proxy and I got XHR error when I tried to download extensions. This solution fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and /usr/share/applications does not exist. Can you tell me where it is in ubuntu?

Comment: I tried various things, and only this worked. TY!

Comment: @Terry So happy it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

in ubuntu go to settings -> wifi -> click on gear icon -> IP4 -> dns input
and put

```
8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

and click apply,
to DNS Resolver Cache open terminal and type:-

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

restart your device

Answer (score 4):

For windows

```
    cd "C:\Users\<user>\Appdata\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code"
    code.exe --ignore-certificate-errors
```

Comment: This works for me except I can use `code.cmd` instead of `code.exe` and it's on the path so I don't need to change directory.

Answer (score 3):

The solution

1. clear DNS cache using command on Windows cmd:
   ipconfig /flushdns
2. change the default DNS servers in your router settings to Google's:

   8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4  >> for IPv4

   2001:4860:4860::8888 , 2001:4860:4860::8844  >> for IPv6

   This link will guide you how to change the DNS server in windows and mac:
   https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/how-to-change-dns-server/
3. restart VSCode and try installing extensions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a corporate network and it's locked down the one last resort is to manually download the VSIX from the website on a domain that will allow it and then copy over the VSIX and install it.

Answer (score 1):

I got this "XHR failed" error in Visual Studio Code.

So I changed my network settings to use Google Public DNS ([instructions](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using))

Finally following [instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34385) (by mohamed-mokhtar) solved for me:

- Go to : Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
- Choose your connection network and ( right click on it then choose properties )
- Select " Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and then click on properties in the bottom of this section
- At General section click on " Use the following DNS Server address : "
- Make " Preferred DNS server : 8.8.8.8 " (if you face a problem check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1090131/the-dns-server-is-not-a-valid-ip-address-error))
- Make " Alternate DNS server : 8.8.4.4 "
- Restart VS code

Answer (score 1):

referring to **@Seif A.** answer

The solution (in case you live in **Egypt**)

clear DNS cache using command on Windows cmd:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

change the default DNS servers in your router settings to Google's:

```
8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4  >> for IPv4
2001:4860:4860::8888 , 2001:4860:4860::8844  >> for IPv6
```

restart **VSCode** and try installing extensions.

Comment: @MuhammedMoussa yes, I mentioned that it is for windows CMD

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while adding new extension in vs code.
I Recognized the problem within the ISP in Egypt, so I changed the DNS in My router to Google DNS Providers , and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just install a VPN like betternet or any other VPN software and change the country to the USA or try other countries.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i have faced today. i was unable to install Prettier extension in vs code then i found this .VSIX file that helped me to solve the problem easily. following are the steps.

1. Go to this link (https://www.vsixhub.com/vsix/47/)
2. [Download this .VSIX file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GztdF.jpg) from above link.
3. after installation of .VSIX file in your local pc, open VS code
4. open "Extensions" or [ctrl+shift+x]
5. type "Prettier" in search bar.
6. [click on three dots as highlighted in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5RFo.jpg) in VS code
7. At the bottom - click on (Install from VSIX...) and select your .VSIX file which you have previously downloaded ["prettier-vscode-10.1.0_vsixhub.com.vsix"]
8. your "Prettier" extension will be installed successfully.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was need to disable work VPN to download extension