# Visual Studio Code Extensions Not Working Without VPN

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed the **Visual Studio Code** and the extensions list is displayed in the extensions section, but the images and descriptions are not. "**Error will installing**" is displayed when I click the install button!

[image]

The log in output:

```
[2022-06-24 21:28:10.503] [renderer1] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://xdebug.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/xdebug/php-debug/1.27.0/1654811147440/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-06-24 21:28:25.692] [renderer1] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://xdebug.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/xdebug/php-debug/1.27.0/1654811147440/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-06-24 21:28:25.720] [renderer1] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://xdebug.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/xdebug/php-debug/1.27.0/1654811147440/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-06-24 21:28:41.479] [renderer1] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://xdebug.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/xdebug/extension/php-debug/1.27.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-06-24 21:28:41.505] [renderer1] [error] XHR timeout: undefinedms: Error: XHR timeout: undefinedms
    at XMLHttpRequest.v.ontimeout (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:83:27861)
[2022-06-24 21:28:56.128] [renderer1] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://xdebug.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/xdebug/extension/php-debug/1.27.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-06-24 21:28:56.164] [renderer1] [error] Error: XHR timeout: undefinedms
    at XMLHttpRequest.v.ontimeout (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:83:27861)
[2022-06-24 21:28:56.201] [renderer1] [error] XHR timeout: undefinedms: Error: XHR timeout: undefinedms
    at XMLHttpRequest.v.ontimeout (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:83:27861)
[2022-06-24 21:28:56.397] [renderer1] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://xdebug.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/xdebug/extension/php-debug/1.27.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
```

When I using **VPN** everythings is working:
[image]

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough info to know for sure, but I will say, MANY companies will blanket ban entire countries from access to their servers just as a security protection.  Thus, maybe the VPN lets you bypass the filter, and it allows the passing of the data to you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75957419/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/74872565/11107541

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your operator, but with Bouygues Telecom in France I do have the same problem with Chrome Extensions. My only workaround is to use a VPN as well.
I think you should try to contact your operator and ask them if they blocked anything related to your logs.

If you can't, have you tried running it as an administrator as well? As for me, it worked when I had a similar issue on my old laptop.

I would also recommend trying to open a CMD in admin and type the following command :

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

And change the default DNS servers in your router or card settings to Google's 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4.

Links to similar issues :

- [Why is VSCode "Unable to open Extension. An unknown error occurred."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190800/why-is-vscode-unable-to-open-extension-an-unknown-error-occurred)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34385