# I've had problem when i want install extensions in the VSCODE on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code

About a week ago I installed windows 10 on my PC. After that I installed VSCODE, but when I try to install extensions in VSCODE the following error occured, and couldn't fix it so far, and I couldn't find an answer searching on the internet. I have had two windows on my PC, windows 7 and windows 10. VSCODE properly work on windows 7, but in windows 10 doesn't. Both windows are using the same internet connection. I've also set my proxy to auto, but it didn't work.

The content error is:
**'the editor could not be opend due to unexpected error:XHR timeout:undefinedms'**

I googled my problem, but I didn't find an answer. I manipulate proxy setting but I can't fix it.

Comment: There's this github issue with the same problem https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165577 it could be region related

Comment: unfortunately it does not work