# XHR timeout: undefinedms in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm unable to install any extension on vscode, even whenever I search for an extension, it doesn't load i get this error
"The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: XHR timeout: undefinedms"
It always redirect me to download locally and install via VSIX, even after manual install extension still doesn't work.

I have tried turning on Http:support proxy on but this doesn't solve the issue.

I recently installed linux with WSL manually on my windows not sure if this is the cause but it seems to me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75957419/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72747375/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74872565/11107541