# vscode window not responding

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2010, vscode-debugger

- VS Code Version: 1.77.0
- OS Version:  windows 11 22h2

this is the issue that I am receiving for the past few days, I have used nodejs and I do not have any Python or other software installed

I have deleted all the extensions and deleted cache

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhFeq.png)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76101193/11107541

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a problem caused due to the recent *McAfee AV* Update. If you have McAfee AV, try putting `code.exe` in the excluded files under Real-Time Scanning.

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177570