# Visual Studio Code extensions disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I start Visual Studio Code (Win10[64bit]), click on extensions overview, all my extensions disappeared. The overview is empty. I also can't load any new ones. But I think all the extensions seem to work. 
In Addition there is a clock on the extensions symbol and it seems "loading", but nothing happens. Waiting a long time or restart didn't improve anything.

This is my first question, thanks for help.

Comment: And you are getting no error notification - typically a flyout in the lower right corner?  You might review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61172590/extension-host-unexpectedly-teminated-vscode in case it is related but you should be getting an error notification if it is the same problem.

Comment: No, there is no error notification.

Comment: perhaps try to repair the installation of visual studio code? Control panel > programs > programs and features, find visual studio code and click repair

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, I re-installed and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by the OP above:

> Thanks for your ideas, I re-installed and everything is fine now.

The hint came from Maja Okholm:

> perhaps try to repair the installation of visual studio code? Control panel > programs > programs and features, find visual studio code and click repair

Comment: The only option I get is Uninstall when I double-click on it.

Comment: @ShaounakNasikkar Try running the setup.exe again. Maybe modifying is not possible any more. Be sure to save your settings in case you have to uninstall it first.