# "liveSass.command.watchMySass not found" and "Extension host terminated unexpectedly” in vs code on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

#### Problem

- **"liveSass.command.watchMySass not found"** and **"Extension host terminated unexpectedly”** in vs code on windows 10 while using live-sass-compiler extension.

#### Failed attempts:

1. manually deleted the extension from the .vscode folder and reinstalled it as per [#219](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/219)
2. [Antivirus/defender] tried excluding the `extensionHostProcess.js` file at `C:\Users\ (user file name e.g- hp...etc) \AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VSCode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js` as per [#94858](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94858)
3. Disabled all extensions and tried running as per [#94807](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94807)
4. Tried restoring quarantined files from antivirus/defender
5. Tried all the aforementioned steps again after reinstalling vs code.
6. downloaded vscode - January 2020 (version 1.42) build as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133333/11045279

#### Error log

```
c:\Users\ADITYA\.vscode\extensions\ritwickdey.live-sass-3.0.0\node_modules\sasslib\sass.sync.js:61
var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var key;

for(key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}

Module["arguments"]=[];
Module["thisProgram"]="./this.program";
Module["quit"]=(function(status,toThrow){throw toThrow});Module["preRun"]=[];Module["postRun"]=[];

var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;

var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;
if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]){if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="WEB"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=true}

else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="WORKER"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=true}

else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="NODE"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=true}

else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="SHELL"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=true}

else{throw new Error("Module['ENVIRONMENT'] value is not valid. must be one 
of: WEB|WORKER|NODE|SHELL.")}}else{ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof 
window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importSc

Error: Import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" could not be resolved.
    at File.load (D:\Projects\vscode-ext-color-highlight\node_modules\file-importer\index.js:130:1)
    at D:\Projects\vscode-ext-color-highlight\node_modules\file-importer\index.js:136:1
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)

abstractExtensionService.ts:155 Extension host terminated unexpectedly. Code:  7  Signal:  null
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fix so you don't have the nightmare I've been having.

Uninstall live sass and close VScode.

For Windows, type the following into file explorer:

%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions

Then delete the folder for live sass. Should be called something like:

ritwickdey.live-sass-3.0.0

Open VScode, reinstall live sass.

Done

Answer (score -3):

The problem **that's not about installation**  **problem**, that's need to open VS Code editor and then create new file with SCSS format. For example, style.scss, and please wait for second and then you see watch sass in below of vscode.

Comment: The above error is thrown when the extension host is terminated which means there is no way the sass extension would work post this error, unless we somehow restart the host.