# How to solve the problem"Python extension loading..." in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I open a python file, Visual Studio Sode show "Python extension loading...". After a while, it shows this error: "Extension host terminated unexpectedly."

I have tried:

1. uninstall all extensions and reinstall.
2. uninstall visual studio code completely and reinstall.
3. change my environment path and remove ";;" .....

This problem happened in windows10.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457994/receiving-error-message-extension-host-terminated-unexpectedly-in-visual-stud) to disable unrelated extensions and check whether there are related git usages.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `telemetry.enableTelemetry` as described in the original answer has been deprecated. Please use this instead:

```json
"telemetry.telemetryLevel": "all|error|crash|off"
```

#### Original answer

Try to disable telemetry in the user settings:

```json
"telemetry.enableTelemetry": false
```

Comment: Change this setting a reload - fixed the issue for me using vscode insiders 1.75.0

Answer (score 0):

Change back to an older version, I'm also having this issue, I switched back to the older version and now its fixed.