# python VS code jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Hey guys I am trying to use jupyter notebook in vs code but when I am installing jupyter  Extention this message pop up "Extension host terminated unexpectedly."

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is there is another extension that is causing this.

If you have `live-server` installed try removing it and then reinstalling `Jupyter Notebook` again.

As a last resort, try remove all other extensions and then install `Jupyter Notebook` extension.

Read more about it from here-
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457994/receiving-error-message-extension-host-terminated-unexpectedly-in-visual-stud)